# Block special file for first session of multisession CD

Tags: devices, block-device, data-cd, audio-cd

I have a multisession CD.  The first session is CD audio tracks and the second is an SVCD q.v. "CD Extra" and "Blue book".  When played on a CD player, the audio tracks are (until recently) heard; when played on an appropriate video player, the SVCD (until recently) plays.  The two "until recently"s in that description highlight my problem -- the disk is starting to degrade and I need to extract the data from it.  My go-to for this task is [GNU ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/).  However, ddrescue interacts with a device special file, not a mounted volume.  (So the "session=*x*" option to `mount` for various optical medium filesystems is useless.)  For convenience, suppose that `/dev/sr0` is the device special file that unhelpfully only represents the last session on the disc (as can be seen from `cdrom.c`'s description of the `CDROMMULTISESSION` ioctl).  Is there a way to

- issue an IOCTL to `/dev/sr0` to change which session it is bound to,
- invoke `mknod` that will somehow bind the resulting device file to a particular session, or
- create a set of block special devices for each session of a multisession disc (similar to sda1, sda2, ..., sda*n* for partitions on a fixed disk)?

(For bonus points, is there a standard container for multisession disks that allow the extracted ISOs to be combined so the entire medium is presented to WINE, dosemu, and/or VM software?  This would be handy for another multisession CD I have -- session 1 is a Win98SE only (and I mean seriously, ONLY, neither WINE nor WinMe nor subsequent Windowss have been able to run this binary) program that uses the audio tracks in session 2.  My last machine that can still run Win98SE is fine, but that won't last forever -- when it fails, I need to be able to present that multisession disk to a VM in a format that works.  Maybe there's a sneaky way to abuse `loop` for this purpose.)

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to do that with the block devices. And `ddrescue` is not very suitable for recovery from failing CD's, you need a different strategy for that. `cdparanoia` uses such a strategy to recover audio tracks with overlapping reads. I am not aware of any program that does anything similar for data CDs, in particular with multi sessions, and taking advantage of the ECC information the CD SCSI command give you. I guess somebody needs to write one ...

Comment: @dirkt : I observe that a similar problem holds for DVDs and BDs (although perhaps your use "CD" is meant generically), which I mention because the `cdparanoia` methods use the layers of "extra information"  (contrast the `CDROMREADMORE1`, `CDROMREADMORE2`, `CDROMREADRAW`, and `CDROMREADALL` ioctls) that are not directly accessible from the DVD and BD drivers.

Comment: CDs have a single spiral track (as it was modelled after a record), DVDs and BDs have circular tracks. CDs have timing information mixed in the data stream (though red book data CDs have additional headers), and different CD drives have different latency in decoding that timing information, while DVDs and BDs have proper headers. So while you are right, and ECC is more exposed (if the drive supports it) on all of CDs/DVDs/BDs in contrast to harddisks, the physical layout of CDs still make it a very different problem, with different best algorithms for recovery.

Comment: Also, please do have a look at the SCSI layer instead of thinking in "ioctls" - you can completely control all drives on this layer. SCSI commands for all kinds of drives are documented, and the kernel interface is easy to use.

Comment: You did not mention what type of CD that is since CDs have plenty of different possible sector modes and sizes.  I recommend to start with analyzing the CD by calling `cdrecord -minfo -v` to get a list of tracks and modes and to have a look at `readcd` since that program works at `SCSI` level and incorporates the resque support from `sdd`.

Comment: @schily : `cdrecord -msinfo` is not documented to work with a multisession disc in which all sessions are closed, like my example disc.  But I'll give it a try.  My experience with `readcd` is that its output is not scripting-friendly.

Comment: @EricTowers I wrote `cdrecord -minfo -v` **not** `-msinfo`. You need the **media info**, not the info to continue an open disk.

Comment: @schily : `Bad option -minfo.`  Additionally, `-minfo` does not appear on the `cdrecord` man page on the local system ([similar example](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cdrecord) ).  Likewise, I didn't write `-msfinfo`.

Comment: @EricTowers The helpful comments unfortunately have been removed. So let me repeat: I cannot help if you are using a 16 year old cdrecord instead of a recent version. The `-msinfo` option was added 15 years ago, If you do not sent the requested information from `cdrecord -minfo -v`, I canot answer your questeion.